# How to only send Facebook Updates to friends who play a game?

Tags: facebook

I've gotten really into this one Facebook Game, some of my friends play it but most of them don't. Before they kill me, is there a way to ONLY publish updates for my friends who play the game?

EDIT: I am looking specifically for how to publish updates a specific way. I can tell everyone That they just have to block it, but that is kind of rude if there is an alternative on my end, and not publishing means that the people who do play won't gain as many benefits from interacting with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot this was here. What I did was add the people who played the game to a list, and then when asked who I wanted to publish to. I selected specific people, and typed in the lists name.

Comment: yes, lists are the right way to do this

Answer (score 4):

Options:

1) Go into settings and do not allow the game to publish updates to your wall.

2) **Tell all your friends that they can click the "Block" button next to any one of your posts and choose to block that application.**

It's surprising how few people know about the second one.

Comment: That's because the block button is hidden until you hover near it. Dumb design IMO

Answer (score 2):

I believe the concept here from the game developers is to get the word out that you play the game.  I believe you can tell Facebook not to allow a specific game to publish updates on your wall at all, which might be a better option if your offending your other friends by numerous updates.